# segmentation fault in getword

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, kernighan-and-ritchie

Hi this is a question regarding the Kernighan and Ritchie keyword count program (Chapter 6 section 3 of the ANSI edition). I've included the entire code in the link below.

When I try to run the code on any C source code I don't get any output. So in an attempt to pinpoint the problem, I've printed statements at different points in the code. The output of the program (when applied on itself) in the terminal window looks like this now:

```
./a.out < keywords.c
I've got past the beginning of the getword loop.
I've got past the beginning of the getword loop.
I'm past the word[0] condition.
Segmentation fault
```

When I use another search method (linear search through a struct key array)I get another combination of the same output, this time without the segmentation fault. Going by the output from the printf statements, I'm inclined to think that there's something wrong with the getword function. So what's causing these errors?

The following is the entire code with both binary and linear search functions:

http://pastebin.com/sPEYYge6

Comment: It would be so much easier to pinpoint the problem using a debugger than using console output.  Suggest you spend some time setting up and learning about a debugger on your platform.

Answer (score 4):

Your code calls into `binsearch()` and tries to use `mid` to access the array `tab` but `mid` was never initialized, so you're dieing there.

```
int binsearch (char * word, struct key tab[], int n) {
    int cond;
    int low, high, mid; 

    low = 0;
    high = n -1;
        // Missing setting mid here!    

    while (low <= high) {
        if ((cond = strcmp(word,tab[mid].word)) < 0) // That's going to be bad...
```

Answer (score 1):

The segmentation fault was correctly diagnosed by Mike as being caused by using the uninitialised `mid` in `binsearch`.

Further mistakes in your code (I'm not 100% sure I spotted all) are:

- Your `getch()` is wrong, `return (bufp > 0) ? BUFF[bufp--] : getchar();` returns the char at index `bufp`, if that is `> 0`, but `bufp` is the number of elements stored in the buffer, that should be `--bufp` there.
- In `ungetch`, the test `if (bufp > BUFFSIZE)` should use `>=`.

The reason you never find any keywords is (with more conventional indentation and spacing):

```
// You loop until you find a non-space character
while (isspace(c = getch())) {
    ;
}
// If it's not a letter, this is not a word, return here
if (!isalpha(c)) {
    *w = '\0';
    return c;
}
// If it was a letter, read the following letters and store them in the buffer
for ( ; --lim > 0; w++) {
    if (!isalnum(*w = getch())) {
        ungetch(*w);
        break;
    }
}
```

that you never store the first letter of any word, so when encountering `volatile`, only `olatile` is stored in the buffer.

Simply adding `*w++ = c;` between the `if` and the `for` loop fixes it, and your programme works (when the `getch` and `ungetch` fixes are also made).